# Problems with Shaders in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glut, freeglut

I'm trying to use stuff like glShaderSource in C++.
Visual Studio says that functions like glCompileShader or glCreateProgram dont exist.
I use FreeGLUT to include OpenGL. Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On windows, anything beyond GL1.1 must be loaded via the extension mechansim. The most convenient way to do so is by using a [GL loader](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) like [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).